# Sending push notification to existing gcm user from fcm on web

Tags: firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I imported my gcm project to fcm. How can I send push notification to the existing users of GCM? I am using it for web notifications. Everywhere I got the support for android and IOS. How to sent notifications on chrome using the gcm ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is related to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466299/use-gcm-token-for-push-messages-in-fcm).

So, it is said that FCM and GCM messaging api are the same. The difference is just their url, GCM - `gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/` and FCM - `fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/` and still pointing to same server.

Furthermore, you can see this documentation about [Update server endpoints](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#update_server_endpoints)

You can also refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623046/how-to-use-an-existing-gcm-token-within-another-firebase-project) for further reading.