# Sending out Push Notifications from PushSharp through FCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, pushsharp

We had an issue with the PushSharp(V2.2.1) in sending out Push Notifications to Android using GCM. So it was decided to use the latest FCM with the latest version of PushSharp (V4.0.10) .

My doubt is whether push sharp will send out notifications to the device tokens obtained from old App users which will have GCM implemented in them.(I am asking so because FCM claims to be the new version for GCM).

will FCM need new device token registered through their servers.?

Or will we be required to maintain 2 Schedulers to send out notifications to Android using GCM and FCM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that you can send notifications to both FCM and GCM users that are still using the old GCM implementation build by migrating the old GCM google project into the FireBase console.

We have tested and found to be working without any issues. We were able to send notifications to old GCM builds with the old device token registered by them.

Please refer this article 
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm

**EDIT:**

You can also refer this link in which few more options are provided inn case you are not able to make do with the above solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/37623763/4405558

Comment: Did you have to make changes to the app?  Or just configure Firebase and hook it up to your app's ProjectID?  Thanks!

Comment: No Changes in the app ,just migrate from GCM to firebase. When the tokens from GCM expire it will automatically get new tokens from FCM.